# Syntax Errors in Java

Tags: java, syntax-error

```
if ( year % 4 == 0 )
    int i = 0;
else
    int j = 0;
```

The syntax errors which crop up in eclipse due to this line of code are:

- Syntax error on token "int", delete this token
- i cannot be resolved to a variable
- Syntax error on token "int", delete this token
- j cannot be resolved to a variable
- Syntax error on token "=", delete this token

I have no clue why this is happening.

From what I have observed, I think putting an int declaration in the if else construct body is making it happen.

If i declare i and j earlier in the code and the run the program then the error vanishes like:

```
int i; int j;
if ( year % 4 == 0 )
    i = 0;
else
    j = 0;
```

No syntax error in this case. Why?

Comment: I was writing an answer; but since its closed I can't. Look at the JLS for [the if statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9), if you go up you'll see that a `LocalVariableDeclarationStatement` can only be in a `Block`

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because of scope.  Declaring i and j inside of the if makes them unreachable outside of the if statement.  Declaring them outside changes their scope.